# Default Value attribute with a dictionary

Tags: c#, attributes

I am trying to use the defaultvalue attribute  [Default Value Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute?view=netcore-3.1)

So I know how to do a default attribute with a string

```
 [DefaultValue("This is the message")]
```

But how do I do a default value for a dictionary ?

I tried this

```
   [DefaultValue(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "Test", "test" } })]
```

but I get this error

> Error CS0182  An attribute argument must be a constant expression,
> typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute
> parameter type

Comment: You can't. Attribute parameters have to be const expressions, and constructing an object isn't. There is no way to accomplish what you want if you have to use `DefaultValueAttribute`.

Comment: I am surprised [there is no good](https://www.google.com/search?q=Error+CS0182+An+attribute+argument+must+be+a+constant+expression,+typeof+expression+or+array+creation+expression+of+an+attribute+parameter+type+site:stackoverflow.com) canonical answer for this error. For what you need `DefaultValueAttribute` with dictionary as a value? Serialization? Certain control (winforms? wpf?)? Something else?

Comment: I want to give a default value for https://swagger.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Dictionary in any attribute, but you can try to add your own attribute with key + value.

I don't know how do you want to use it, but I'd recommend trying something like:

```
public class DictionaryDefaultAttribute : DefaultValueAttribute
{
    public DictionaryDefaultAttribute(string key, string value) 
        : base(new Dictionary<string, string>() {{key, value}})
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a Dynamic Dictionary, the following code also worked for me. ```    [DefaultValue("{\"Field1\": \"Value1\",\"Field2\": \"Value2\",\"Field3\":\"Value3\"}")]
    [Required]
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> Fields { get; set; }```